# How to enable headphones on Lenovo Thinkpad Edge E430?

Tags: 12.04, headphones

I've a lenovo thinkpad edge e430. I use headphones provided by lenovo. Today afternoon I did an update and now my headphones aren't working in Ubuntu. Sucks not being ablet o hear music while programming.

Is anyone facing similar problem? Any known fix?

Answer (score 0):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure

You can aslo execute this command and reboot:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa; sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get dist-upgrade; sudo apt-get install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils gdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2; sudo apt-get -y --reinstall install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils gdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2; killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.pulse*; sudo usermod -aG `cat /etc/group | grep -e '^pulse:' -e '^audio:' -e '^pulse-access:' -e '^pulse-rt:' -e '^video:' | awk -F: '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's:,$::g'` `whoami`
```

The command will work even it will produce many errors

**Another Solution you can try the following:**

1. Open the terminal and edit the alsa-base.conf file with this command:

   `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
2. At the end of the file, add this line:

   `options snd-hda-intel model=eapd probe_mask=1 position_fix=1`
3. Press Ctrl+Q and save your file, then reboot your system so that new changes take effect.

Audio will now be restored to your Headphones.

Good luck!